# Chrome render bug when sliding images

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fonts, flexslider

I'm using a JS slider called Flexslider and have discovered a strange text rendering issue. When the image switches to the next one Google Chrome (Windows/OSX) seems to change the font weight on all text elements on the web page. This issue doesn't occur in FF/IE.

Do you know why this is happening? I've tried using different fonts without success. Please have a look at my example screenshots to see the difference.

[image: Normal image]

[image: When sliding]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most definitely because the slider script uses hardware-accelerated css transforms. It has been known to change the antialias technique when applied to webkit, even to unrelated elements. Here is a demo that proves it: http://jsfiddle.net/378pN/

You can’t really do much about it. If you want to keep using css transforms, you will need to change the way the browser antialiases the texts. You can force it to use the skinnier version (I think it’s "normal" antialias, not sub-pixel) by adding:

```
html{-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/378pN/1/

This way it won’t change the way it renders text when adding CSS transforms.

Comment: @alex23 the first fiddle does the same in my safari 6.01

Answer (score 1):

Could you please post your code? It's most likely an unclosed tag. It could also be that the slider and the changing images are changing the height of the element and it's affecting the text below it because they are moving just a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Tis problem has an easy Solution. For example you have an **image-slider**, which changes text-rendering, just use the **CSS Codes below** for the **Slider-Div.**

```
position: relative; 
z-index: 1;
```

Thats all  :)

Comment: Had a similar issue, but it was doing this with text as well. Thanks it worked like a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code, it's hard to tell. My guess would be a tag that isn't closed properly. You should run your page through the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and correct any errors you find. If it still persists, you'll need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the other answers adding some code would be useful, failing that, if flex slider uses css3 transitions you could try -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); on the text elements that are changing aliasing, this helped me fix a similar issue i was experiencing with another js slider plugin called Fotorama.js